# Using tablesorter custom parser only for filtering

Tags: tablesorter

I have a table with checkbox column for which filter is used so I can get only selected rows.
I've added custom parser for that column to use checkboxes' "checked" prop values for filtering.

The thing is that parser is added to column using 'sorter' property in 'headers' option for tablesorter initializer, so that when I click on some checkbox and trigger 'update' event, sorting is applied to checkbox column and selected rows are moved to the bottom of the table.

Is there a way to add parser to column so that it's used only for filtering, not for sorting?

**UPD**: I think I should clarify what I'm trying to do.
I have a custom parser for checkboxes that looks like the following:

```
var myCustomParser = {
    id: 'myCustomParser',
    is: function() { return false; },
    format: function(cellText, table, cellNode, cellIndex) {
        return $(cellNode).find('.checkbox-to-find').prop('checked') ? '1' : '0';
    },
    parsed: true,
    type: 'text'
};
```

Then I add it to tablesorter and use in initializer:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser(myCustomParser);
//...
$table.tablesorter({
    // ...
    headers: {
        0: {sorter: 'myCustomParser'}
    },
    //...
);
```

This enables filtering but sorting is also applied. I have a checkbox for selecting all rows in header cell for that column and when I click it sorting is applied and checkboxes are sorted.
This is what I use for now to disable sorting:

```
$table.tablesorter({
    //...
    textSorter: {
        0: function() { return 0; }
    },
    headers: {
        0: {sorter: 'myCustomParser'}
    },
    //...
);
```

Stub sorter practically disables sorting while leaving filter enabled. But this seems wrong. According to [docs](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#parsers) I can't use `parser` option for setting parser name. `filter` option also seems to be only for `false` and `parsed` values. I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
$table.tablesorter({
    // ...
    headers: {
        0: {parser: 'myCustomParser'}
    },
    //...
);
```

If this would enable parsing (and make filtering use these parsed values) while keeping sorting disabled, that would be great.

**P.S.** I've found out there's a [parser for checkboxes](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/parsers/parser-input-select.js) in repo, but the question remains: how do I specify parser so that sorting is not enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you are using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/). If that is the case, setting the column to not sort does not stop the parser from processing the information in that column. Here is some information you may have missed in the documentation.

Column features (sort, filter or parsing) can be disabled using any of the methods within the associated section (they all do the same thing), in order of priority:

### Disable sort ([ref](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-options-headers.html))

Parsing of column content still occurs

- jQuery data `data-sorter="false"`.
- Metadata `class="{ sorter: false }"`. This requires the metadata plugin.
- Headers option `headers : { 0 : { sorter: false } }`.
- Header (`<th>`) class name `class="sorter-false"`.

### Disable filter ([ref](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html#classes))

- jQuery data `data-filter="false"`.
- Metadata `class="{ filter: false }"`. This requires the metadata plugin.
- Headers option `headers : { 0 : { filter: false } }`.
- Header (`<th>`) class name `class="filter-false"`.

  If using the "all" column external filter, the disabled column will be included in the query. You can exclude the disabled column by setting a range in the column attribute of the external filter ([ref](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-external-inputs.html))

  ```
  <input class="search" type="search" data-column="0-2,4,6-7">
  ```

### Disable parsing ([ref](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#headers))

When parsing is disabled, both sorting and filtering are automatically disabled, and the column data stored within the cache is set to an empty string.

- jQuery data `data-parser="false"`.
- Metadata `class="{ parser: false }"`. This requires the metadata plugin.
- Headers option `headers : { 0 : { parser: false } }`.
- Header (`<th>`) class name `class="parser-false"`.

---

Update: In your case, I would disable sorting (using any sorter methods above), then use a custom [`textExtraction` function](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#textextraction) that targets the column containing checkboxes:

```
textExtraction : {
    0 : function(node, table, cellIndex) {
        return $(node).find('.checkbox-to-find').prop('checked') ? '1' : '0';
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is my parser is custom so it needs to be assigned to column in some way. The only way I've managed to find is described [here](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers.html) and it uses sorter property. I tried 'parser' instead of 'sorter', didn't work with version 2.17.4 that we use. Currently I'm using textSorter option with "return 0" sorter for that column.

Comment: I've looked into tablesorter.min.js code that we use, and there's no note about you being the maintainer, so it's probably not your fork. I'll try to use version from your GH repo tomorrow and see if something changes.

Comment: If the comments have been stripped away, you can tell the code is from my fork by getting a version number from the console: `$.tablesorter.version`; the value will be `undefined` in the original.

Comment: Tablesorter version was displayed when I tried this, "2.17.4", so I guess it was your fork in the end. Edited the question to clarify the situation.

Comment: `textExtraction` works with `sorter` option set to `false` **and** `filter` option set to `parsed`. Thank you for your help.